# Xcode custom framework store data differently for widget & main app

Tags: xcode, core-data, swiftui, frameworks, widget

**Core data in my custom framework stores data separately for its widget and main app. The widget doesn't load data stored from the main app. Is there any solution to fetch data from a widget that is stored from main app?**

Code in framework:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
public class CoreDataManager {
    public static let shared = CoreDataManager()
    let identifier = "com.Appnap.DataBaseFramework"
    let model = "CoreDataModel"
    
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let messageKitBundle = Bundle(identifier: self.identifier)
        let modelURL = messageKitBundle!.url(forResource: self.model, withExtension: "momd")!
        let managedObjectModel =  NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)
        
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: self.model, managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel!)
        container.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in
                if let err = error{
                        fatalError("❌ Loading of store failed:\(err)")
                }
        }
                            
        return container
        
    }()
    
    //MARK: - Append data
    
    public func createTask(task: String){
            
            let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
            let contact = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Task", into: context) as! Task
            
            contact.id = UUID()
            contact.taskdescription = task
            
            do {
                try context.save()
                print("✅ Person saved succesfuly")
                
            } catch let error {
                print("❌ Failed to create Person: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
    }
    
    //MARK: - Fetch data
    
    public func fetch() -> [String] {
        var data = [String]()
            let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
            
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Task>(entityName: "Task")
            
            do{
                
                let allTask = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                
                for (_,task) in allTask.enumerated() {
                    print(task.taskdescription!)
                    data.append(task.taskdescription!)
                }
                
            }catch let fetchErr {
                print("❌ Failed to fetch Person:",fetchErr)
            }
        return data
    }
}
```

I just called the "createTask" & "fetch" functions from main app and widget. But main app and widget stores data in different container.

[image: my app]

Comment: Can you share the code that you are having issues with?

Comment: Edited, please check.